# responseXML property in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml

i am using responseXML property in javascript , but it shows an error that xml document ($strXml) is invalid, i dont know where is the problem in my code, plz help me

**html file:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Home Page</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script> 
</head>
<body >
<form> 
<input type="text" id="code"  name="code" size="10" />
<input name="submit" type = "button" onClick ="check()"  value = "check" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a go with `application/xml` instead of `text/xml`.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure there is no whitespace before the XML prolog. (i.e. the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, which should be right at the beginning of the document)

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the code after `if ($code == $codee)` as

```
 {
   $product= $xml->createElement( 'product' );
   $xml->appendChild( $product );

   $pname = $xml->createElement('pname',$name);
   $product->appendChild( $pname );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Append a timestamp to the url be sure that you get a fresh xml:

```
var url = "coding.php?cod=" + cod+'&'+new Date().getTime();
```